# pthread_kill(), how to send signals and catch them in a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

I am writing a simple program that generates signals (SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2, but currently I am only worried about SIGUSR1) until the user terminates the program, these signals are then sent to a thread to catch and log them.

The child process is in charge of creating the thread to receive the signals.

I believe I install the handler correctly, as well as the signal mask.

Originally, the signals would generate but the thread wouldn't receive and catch them. I was using `kill()` to send the signal. I switched to using the pthread library version of `pthread_kill()`, which now results in a segmentation fault.

Just a little lost on where I am going wrong and would appreciate any input!

Here's what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

pthread_t reporter_thread;
struct sigaction sa;
sigset_t new_sig_set; // set up mask

void handle_SIGUSR1(int sig)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "SIGUSR1 received", 20);
}

void * reporter(void *arg)
{
    printf("Entered reporter thread\n");
    //empty mask
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &new_sig_set, NULL);
    while(1){
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* set up the signal masks */
    sigemptyset(&new_sig_set); // empty the mask
    sigaddset(&new_sig_set, SIGUSR1); // add SIGUSR1 to the mask
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new_sig_set, NULL); // block SIGUSR1

    /* set up the signal handler */
    sa.sa_handler = handle_SIGUSR1; 
    sa.sa_flags = 0;

    // randomly generate signals every 5 seconds.
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        //will need to exec() sigcatcher.c here
        pthread_create(&reporter_thread, NULL, reporter, NULL);
        printf("Created reporter thread\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new_sig_set, NULL); // block SIGUSR1

        while (1)
        {
            srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
            printf("Generating signal\n");
            //generate a random number between 1 and 2
            int random = rand()%((2+1)-1) + 1;
            if (random == 1)
            {
                printf("Sending signal: SIGUSR1\n");
                pthread_kill(reporter_thread, SIGUSR1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Something else\n");
            }
            sleep(2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ["The pthread_kill() function provides a mechanism for asynchronously directing a signal at a thread *in the calling process*."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html), emphasis added.  You can't use it to signal from one process to another.  Moreover, `reporter_thread` is uninitialized in the parent, and that is likely your segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, several bugs here.

1. As pilcrow says, `pthread_kill` is for sending a signal to a thread in the *same* process.  For signaling another process, you did want `kill()` all along.  (And moreover, the `reporter_thread` object was initialized only in the child process, which has its own memory; it never got initialized at all in the parent.) So why didn't `kill()` work before?  Read on.
2. The main thread of your child process exits immediately after starting the reporter thread: it falls out of the `if (pid == 0)` block and does the next thing in the function, which is nothing: it merely returns from `main`.  This causes all the threads of that process to terminate, including the reporter thread.  Threads do not get to survive the death of the process.  See [`man pthread_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

   > The new thread terminates in one of the following ways:
   > [...]
   >
   > - Any of the threads in the process calls exit(3), or the main
   >   thread performs a return from main().  This causes the
   >   termination of all threads in the process.

   Moreover, the parent process then calls `wait()` to reap the child, so by the time you get around to `kill()`, the child process isn't even a zombie anymore.  If you had checked the return value and `errno` of `kill()` (hint hint), you should have seen `ESRCH`, the target process does not exist.

   So you need to make the child process's main thread keep running after starting the reporter thread.  For instance you could `pthread_join` the reporter thread (which may or may not ever return).  Likewise, the parent needs to *not* call `wait()`; that would never complete since the child process never exits.
3. The reporter thread has a race.  It needs to install the signal handler **before** unblocking the signal; otherwise the signal is likely to arrive before the handler is installed, which would then be fatal.

   The infinite loop of `sigaction` also serves no purpose except to waste CPU.  The default behavior of `sigaction`, unless you specify the `SA_RESETHAND` flag, is that the handler remains installed after the signal is delivered.  Have the reporter thread call `sigaction` only once, then `pthread_sigmask` once, then enter a `while(1) pause();` loop or similar.
4. The `write()` in the signal handler writes 20 bytes of a string that is only 17 bytes long.  gcc issues a warning about this.  Enable all compiler warnings and heed them.
5. It's unnecessary to call `pthread_sigmask` a second time in the parent.  The signal is already blocked, and nobody is going to be sending signals to the parent anyway.  The only reason to call it in the parent at all is to avoid a race by ensuring the child process starts with the signal already blocked.
6. Unrelated, but never call `srand()` in a loop; it is pointless and usually counterproductive.  Just call it once before the first call to `rand()`.

With these fixed, the program works for me.  [Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WzvnTnobG).

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for mentioning some of the unrelated issues, even things like the `srand()` issue will help me improve. Originally I thought I didn't need to use `pthread_join()` since the thread would never terminate, but now I see it is required to make sure that the child doesn't exit, and thus bring the thread with it.